# No identifier specified for entity: XYZ (AnnotationException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

**Entity**

```
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_type")

public class UserType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    //@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    public long id;

    @Column
    //@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    public String name;

    public UserType() {

    }

    public UserType(String name, long id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }



    //@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.haven</groupId>
    <artifactId>Haven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Haven</name>
    <description>Haven-Backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Session**

```
try {
            StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).addAnnotatedClass(UserType.class).getMetadataBuilder().build();

            SessionFactory factory = meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

            UserType ut = new UserType();

            ut.setId(1L);
            ut.setName("customer");
            System.out.println(ut.getId());

            session.saveOrUpdate(ut);
            t.commit();
            System.out.println("successfully saved");
            factory.close();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>      
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/haven</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">u37y5a</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
       

     
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here I'm trying to insert data using session it gives me error

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at com.haven.main.HavenApplication.main(HavenApplication.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I've tried many ways, explained on the internet. its working with CrudRepository, also its creating tables, but using session its not working.

Sometimes it says unable to access property when all properties are public, I've tried downgrading hibernate but no luck. I am using hibernate 5

After removing access type, it started giving

```
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public long com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType#id] : com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType@1d3a4c49
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4931)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4631)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.haven.main.HavenApplication.main(HavenApplication.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType.id to com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.getLong(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getLong(Field.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:65)
    ... 16 more
```

**Update**

when added AccessType on getter and added @Id annotation, new error comes

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType.id
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4931)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4631)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.haven.main.HavenApplication.main(HavenApplication.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:42)
    ... 16 more
```

Any help will be appreciated, Forgive me for any typo and mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

After looking into lots of posts, blogs and examples given by lots of devs, I found that there is no concrete solution for such problem, as the code examples said to be working by devs, are not working on hibernate 5.

Its also suggested to avoid xml configuration and go for annotation based implementation, which I implemented and its working perfectly fine `@Transactional` annotation answers lots of requirements and I'm able to configure it according to my needs.

I'm avoiding session based approach in favour of `@Transactional` annotation

Thanks to those who came forward to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` from the `getName()` and `getId()` methods. You can not use the `AccessType.PROPERTY` and `AccessType.FIELD` simultaneously.

And by the way, you can also remove `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` from the fields because hibernate identify access type by the placement of the `@Id` annotation. See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access).

One more problem what I see, you add your class for mapping two times:

1. Via `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```xml
<mapping class="com.haven.main.lib.dao.UserType" />
```

and

2. Via `addAnnotatedClass`

```java
Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).addAnnotatedClass(UserType.class).getMetadataBuilder().build();
```

You should do it only once.

Comment: Yes, but when I remove it it starts saying PropertyAccessException, object is not same as declared class

Comment: Tried same, still same error. I'm just trying all possible combinations. As I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have made changes, and it started giving different error, please see updated question

Comment: Could you please try to replace `long` by `Long` and also make your fields `id`, `name` - private, since you have appropriate getters/setters.

Comment: I've added new error, please have a look, if this helps.